# Почему нельзя написать else на том же уровне отступов, что и if?

Tags: python

Стояла такая задачка. На входе список чисел, вернуть True если массив содержит где-нибудь 3 рядом с 3.

```
has_33([1, 3, 3]) → True
has_33([1, 3, 1, 3]) → False
has_33([3, 1, 3]) → False
```

Ниже решение.

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 3 and nums[i+1] == 3:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Не понимаю, почему нельзя написать вот так:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 3 and nums[i+1] == 3:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Оператор else считается частью if, без if нельзя использовать else

Comment: Потому, что в первом варианте `else` относится к циклу `for` (т.е. выполнится когда цикл дойдёт до конца), и, по сути, `else` тут лишний. А во втором случае - к условию `if` (но тогда цикл прервётся на первой же итерации, т.к. в обоих случаях стоит `return`).

Answer (score 3):

Здесь else относится не к if, а к for.

Если быть точнее, правильный ответ такой:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 3 and nums[i+1] == 3:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Самый правильный ответ - это вообще выкинуть `else` (чтобы не смущал) и подвинуть последний `return` влево. Ведь `break` я в цикле что-то не наблюдаю.

Answer (score 2):

nukee сказал все верно, я просто поподробнее опишу, что происходит:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 3 and nums[i+1] == 3:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Как только у нас есть `return`, то функция автоматически прекращает выполнение. То есть, если мы напишем что-то такое:

```
def some_function():
    return False
    print('Hello world!')
```

То функции закончится на `return False` и дальше ничего выполнять не будет.

В коде выше Вы проверяете только одну итерацию, если она верна, то возвращаете *True*, иначе *False*. А до второй итерации Вы просто не доходите.

Самый верный код, как подметил, GrAnd будет:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 3 and nums[i+1] == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Так как если совпадений нет, то нам нужно просто вернуть *False*.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас условие задачи **содержит где-нибудь 3 рядом с 3**. Это значит, что если где-то встретилось 3 рядом с 3, то условие выполняется, можно возвращать `True`. Но если поставить `else` следом на том же уровне и вернуть в нём сразу `False`, то это будет значить, что если **не содержит где-нибудь 3 рядом с 3**, то условие не выполняется, а это не так, оно может выполниться в другом месте. Полностью соответствующее обратное условие будет **нигде не содержит 3 рядом с 3**, а это будет известно только когда цикл полностью закончится (**нигде не встретилось**) и только после этого можно ставить `return False`. При этом `else`, как многие уже написали, тут вообще не нужно на самом деле.